Is there a way to build an IPA from Xcode without a paid developers account?
I want to add my apps to my own AltStore and to do that I need to compile them into a .ipa file. Is there a way to do so without a paid Apple Developer Membership account? The only resources I could find online mention that you have to have a paid account, but that doesn't seem right.

Why does it not seem right. During most of the time using PCs you have had to pay for developer tools.

@mmmmmm I thought the whole point of using AltStore was that I didn't have to pay for the membership

no it means you don't pay a proportion of each sale to Apple
